# vb.net how do i find the # of indexes in an array

Tags: arrays

In vb.net I want to split a string into an array, I also want to be able to know how many indices are in the array.

In vb6
I would write it like this

```
 dim v1, arrIN(), idcCount
    v1 = "1,2,3,4,5"
    arrin() = split(v1,",")
    idcCount = ubound(arrin))
```

I can get this to actually put those values into an array using:

```
 Dim arrIN() = Split(v1, ",")
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the count of indices
When I try to test this in the immediate window I get the message below

```
 ?UBound(arrIN())
```

Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `arrVar.GetUpperBound(0)` and `arrVar.GetLowerBound(0)` methods.

Have look at MSDN reference : [Array.GetUpperBound(dimension)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim v1 As String = "1,2,3,4,5"
    Dim arrIN() As String = Split(v1, ",")

    'Gets the total number of elements in the array
    Dim a As Integer = arrIN.Length

    'Gets the index of the last element
    Dim b As Integer = arrIN.GetUpperBound(0)
```

In this instance:

arrIN.Length = 5

arrIN.GetUpperBound(0)=4

The zero in GetUpperBound(0) is the dimension that you want the upper index for.

AVD gave you the right answer.  I just added arrIN.Length just in case you needed it.